# asp.net cssclass vs assigning class to asp.net object directly

Tags: asp.net, css, syntax

I have a lot of code that I am reworking in which a single item is wrapped in a div block with a single linked cssstyle.  There doesn't seem to be any real difference between wrapping the .Net object in the div and applying the style with the "cssstyle" property. Is there any real difference?

```
<div class="grid_1">
      <asp:FormView ID="FormView8" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsInst">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("TestScoresPageNrStudents")%>'>(?)</asp:LinkButton>
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:FormView>
</div>
```

vs

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView8" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsInst" CssClass="grid_1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("TestScoresPageNrStudents")%>'>(?)</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference would be in the first case, it would render:

```
<div class="grid_1">
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```

versus:

```
<table class="grid_1">...</table>
```

This would have an impact on how you would be able to design your css.  My thought is that the first case (the `<div>`) would be preferable since it would gain more flexibility in designing your css classes -- mainly, you would not be restricted to being solely within a table.  Of course, if the `grid_1` class is solely for styling tabular data, then the second case would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need, but basically I guess you should be OK with the second approach since the ASP.NET controls will render some HTML element with the class attribute set to what you specified in CssClass="...".

I think it's best if you look at the HTML code rendered by the ASP.NET controls and if that's OK for you, then you can use the second approach (CssClass="...").

On the other hand, some controls might not exactly render the HTML code you need. E.g. the GridView probably renders a TABLE - if for some reason you really need a DIV element, then you'll have to wrap it as shown in approach one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're keeping this a single item, no. However keep in mind, CSS priority is based on nested levels.

The lower the CSS is applied, the higher the priority it takes over other style classes.

Also, if you add more elements within this div, they will be effected if you keep the style on the container div.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the "grid_1" class attribute is applied to the container  tag.

In the second case, the "grid_1" class attribute is applied to the main tag of the asp:FormView control.

It is possible to define custom CSS rules for different tags, whose class equals "grid_1"